# Getting error "list.remove(x): x not in list" while fetching only wanted elements from XML using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have written a code to remove countries of those ranks which are not present in list `lis` from  `tes.xml` and generating updated xml  `output.xml` after removing the countries. But getting error while generating the output xml
XML:

```
tes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
      </state>  
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>  
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
      </state>  
    </country>
</data>
```

code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('tes.xml')

lis = ['5', '2']
root = tree.getroot()

for country in root.findall('.//country/state'):
  rank = str(country.find('rank').text)
  print(rank)
  if rank not in lis:
    root.remove(country)
tree.write('outpu.xml')
```

error:

```
2
5
69
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    root.remove(country)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

expected output:

```
<data>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
      </state>  
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>  
    </country>
</data>
```

Comment: Please don't change the question after you have received an answer. I explained what the problem is, but now my answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: I didn't change. same question with updated error.

Comment: What? You did change the question. Don't do that. If you have additional problems that were not addressed by my answer, please ask a new question.

Comment: sure sir.. that won't be a problem. I will ask new quest and update this question to old one for which you answered.

Comment: i can post only after 90 mins :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root.remove()` only removes direct children of the root element. The `<country>` elements are indeed direct children, but the `country` variable in the code refers to `<state>` elements.

This works:

```
for country in root.findall('.//country'):
    rank = country.find('state/rank').text
    print(rank)
    if rank not in lis:
        root.remove(country)
```

Comment: I tried the same understanding if extra tag continents is added in XML but again it gave me error. I am just trying to understand how it works